# How to compare API request JSON with existing json document in MongoDb?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

The title of the question is self explanatory. I want to know what differences are there in JSON Document A which comes from API request and JSON Document B which is already in Mongo DB.how to get changes column name and data also.. i am creating log..that's why i want...
Below is the code of what I'm trying:

NodeJS APICode//

```
 function Updatejob(req, res) {
      return function (jobSchedule) {
        var obj = new Date();

        CompareJSON(req, mongodbjson); 
        return Job.create(req.body).then(.....)
        }
```

Already Data in Mongodb before Update Record

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("586d1032aef194155028e9c7"),
  "history" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("586d1032aef194155028e9c4"),
            "updated_by" : "",
            "details" : "Job Created",
            "changetype" : "Created",
            "datetime" : ISODate("2017-01-04T15:09:38.465Z")
        }
    ],
 "current_status" : "Pending",
    "time" : 0
}
```

//REQUEST FOR UPDATE DATA

```
  {
        "_id" : ObjectId("586d1032aef194155028e9c7"),
      "history" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("586d1032aef194155028e9c4"),
                "updated_by" : "",
                "details" : "Job Completed",
                "changetype" : "Completed",
                "datetime" : ISODate("2017-01-04T15:09:38.465Z")
            }
        ],
     "current_status" : "Completed",
        "time" : 0
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsondiffpatch`:

```
 var delta = jsondiffpatch.diff(object1, object2);
```

See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsondiffpatch

Comment: how to get data from mongodb store in variable for compare... var getjob = Job.findById(req.params.id)

Comment: @AddiKhan You can't get it synchronously. You do something like `Job.findById(req.params.id, function (err, getjob) { ...you have the gejob here... });` You can also use promises. See the Mongoose and Mongo docs for details: http://mongoosejs.com/ and https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/

Comment: ya i am using promises  please lets chat with me i need help

Comment: TypeError: Unknown encoding: 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472648/how-to-get-data-from-mongodb-and-save-in-variable

Comment: can you please answer of my this question .... i am very thankful to you